# jQuery .not() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do some operations with elements that have class `show-all` and have no class `disabled`. My code:

```
$('.show-all').not('.disabled').click(function() {
    alert('1');
})
```

But it works too if element has `disabled` class. Can you help me?
Sorry for my english. Thank you in advance.
My code, that works fine now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-all:not(.disabled)').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('li').removeClass('hidden-item');
            $(this).addClass('transparent-50').addClass('disabled');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: this looks like it should work - could you perhaps provide a jsfiddle link, or the full code?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Did you try the `:not` selector instead, i.e. `$('.show-all:not(.disabled)')`?

Comment: @Xion with no space between `all` and `:` unless you want to target the children of `.show-all`

Comment: On jsFiddle it works fine) http://jsfiddle.net/kMrpY/

Comment: @Capsule Right. I edited my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/z5FSp/).

How does your markup differ from the example above?

Answer (score 1):

`not()` is a CSS selector. Do like this:

```
$('.show-all:not(.disabled)').click(function() {
    alert('1');
});
```

Comment: There's no point of using a jQuery method when there's a selector available.

Comment: In this case, no, but the method can be used on an existing jQuery object. Anyway, this doesn't make not() method disappear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
$('.show-all:not(.disabled)').click(function() {
    alert('1');
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2sLM/1/).

Answer (score 1):

It's working the way you have it. Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9BSdy/